# Python fsolve tempering with object

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods

I wrote a script in Python that finds the zero of a fairly complicated function using fsolve. The way it works is as follows. There is a class that simply stores the parameter of the function. The class has an evaluate method that returns a value based on the stored parameter and another method (inversion) that finds the parameter at which the function takes the supplied output.

The inversion method updates the parameter of the function at each iteration and it keeps on doing so until the mismatch between the value returned by the evaluate method and the supplied value is zero.

The issue that I am having is that while the value returned by the inversion method is correct, the parameter, that is part of the object, is *always 0* after the inversion method terminates. Oddly enough, this issue disappears if I use root instead of fsolve. As far as I know, fsolve is just a wrapper for root with some settings on the solver algorithm and some other things enforced.

Is this a known problem with fsolve or am I doing something dumb here? The script below demonstrates the issue I am having on the sine function.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve, root
from math import sin, pi

class invertSin(object):
    def __init__(self,x):
        self.x = x

    def evaluate(self):
        return sin(self.x)

    def arcsin_fsolve(self,y):

        def errorfunc(xnew):
            self.x = xnew
            return self.evaluate() - y

        soln = fsolve(errorfunc, 0.1)
        return soln

    def arcsin_root(self,y):

        def errorfunc(xnew):
            self.x = xnew
            return self.evaluate() - y

        soln = root(errorfunc, 0.1, method = 'anderson')
        return soln

myobject = invertSin(pi/2)
x0 = myobject.arcsin_fsolve(0.5) #find x s.t. sin(x) = 0.5 using fsolve
print(x0) #this prints pi/6
x0obj = myobject.x
print(x0obj) #this always prints 0 no matter which function I invert

myobject2 = invertSin(pi/2)
x1 = myobject2.arcsin_root(0.5) #find x s.t. sin(x) = 0.5 using root
print(x1) #this prints pi/6
x1obj = myobject2.x
print(x1obj) #this prints pi/6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add print statements for `xnew` in the `errorfunc` then you will see that `fsolve` works with a list (of one element). This means that the function is re-interpreted that way, not the original function. Somehow the type information is lost after exiting the solver so that then the address/reference to that list is interpreted as floating point data, which gives the wrong value.

Setting `self.x = xnew[0]` there restores the desired behavior.